# Stored procedure returns 0 record with persian text with ی

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure shown below. When I send a parameter that contains persian letter 'ی' it does not return any record.
I used  N  before but it did not work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [DB].[sp_Acceptor_SelectByDynamicField_ForChart]
    @ProjectType    NVARCHAR(50)=NULL,  
    @FromDate datetime=NULL,
    @ToDate datetime=NULL
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @Where VARCHAR(MAX),
                @SQL   VARCHAR(MAX)           

    SET @Where = ' WHERE 1=1 '

    IF ( @ProjectType IS NOT NULL )
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND  ProjectType = N''' + @ProjectType + ''' '           

    IF ( @FromDate IS NOT NULL  AND  @ToDate IS NOT NULL )
            SET @Where = @Where + ' AND  PmDate BETWEEN    ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),(@FromDate),101) + '''        AND ''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50),@ToDate, 101) + '''  '                                 

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT  * From Acceptor  ' + @Where

    EXEC (@SQL)

END
```

Comment: `ProjectType = N''' + @ProjectType + ''' '` Should be changed to `ProjectType LIKE N''%' + @ProjectType + '%'' '`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it this will fix the problem you are asking about, but there is a better way to write this stored procedure. As is, your stored procedure is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.
Try this instead:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [itnarenj.ir_DB].[sp_Acceptor_SelectByDynamicField_ForChart]
    @ProjectType    NVARCHAR(50)=NULL,  
    @FromDate datetime=NULL,
    @ToDate datetime=NULL
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT *
    FROM Acceptor
    WHERE (ProjectType = @ProjectType OR @ProjectType IS NULL)
    AND (
            @FromDate IS NULL OR @ToDate IS NULL
            OR
            (
            PmDate >= @FromDate
            AND PmDate <= @ToDate
            )        
        )

END
```

Comment: Thanks so much , it fix the problem .. 
thank you soooooooo much